# Text in edit view is not vertically aligned

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I was changing the background of an edit view in Android and I did it with a drawable that contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
    <corners
        android:radius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

Then add it with the "android: background" property to the style of my input:

```
<style name="inputPrimary">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_rounded_background</item>
    <item name="android:padding">9dp</item>
</style>
```

I don't know if I am very detailed but I find that the text in my Edit view is vertically misaligned (a little but it becomes noticeable enough)

[My edit text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsOk4.png)

What can I do?

Comment: Don't forget that there are letters like `g` which reach below the baseline of the normal text. Write `Tg` in your `EditText` and see if you still find it misaligned.

Comment: @RenéSpies Yes, I see that despite putting a 'g' or 'T' the text does not change. It means that it is not for the text but for another factor :(

Comment: No, I don't mean that it should change your alignment. I meant that you should check the alignment relation between T, g and the borders of your `EditText`. Only write `Tg` in your `EditText` and see the distance from the top of the T to the top border and the bottom of the g to the bottom border and check if it looks aligned then. If it does, your `EditText` text just "looks misaligned" because you don't have any letters like `g` in it.

Comment: maybe better show your `EditText` xml code too, you should have `drawableStart` on that view

Comment: @RenéSpies Ohh now I understand. I did it and you're right, the text is aligned but it seems as if it is. However, Thompson sparta's answer is the most accurate, balancing the space.

Comment: It might solve your problem now. Don't forget that your app might be translated into different languages and in those, there might be letters like `g` involved. I would leave it as it is, without messing with the padding, as this is the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the individual padding of the view either in styles or layout xml,then adjust the top and bottom padding to the pressie level you need the text to be.Be careful of the height of the view as the text height+padding top+padding bottom should be less than the views height.

```
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="9dp"
android:paddingLeft="9dp"
android:paddingRight="9dp"
```